# Best Practices for more than one UIWindow in an application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwindow

Experts, Please share the best approaches and practices that must be taken care while adding a UIWindow on top of current window.(Window1) I have a situation where I have locked the orientation of a view "A"  to Portrait in a view controller. Then I create a new UIWindow and make it as key and visible. The root view controller of this new UIWindow is again a view controller which supports all orientations. The issue I am having is whenever I make the previous window (say window1)as key and visible again, and try to rotate the device,eventhough the view stays locked to specific orientation(say Portrait), the status bar is rotating which looks very wierd.

Comment: Why are you using more than one UIWindow? I've never had the need to have more than one UIWindow. Doesn't really make sense why you would. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with 2 windows?

Comment: You should not use more than one UIWindow, are you trying to remove the second UIWindow? You added a second window over the First? Your question is not very clear , in that case you can -resignKeyWindow, but i don't think it's a good practice at all

Comment: I wanted to emulate uiAlertview by a custom view. thats y i followed the approach

Comment: you dont need a window for that. a custom view is just fine.

Comment: as @vikingosegundo stated, you can use a custom view.That's the way to go,but, you can also subclass UIAlertView.

Comment: what would be a custom view, too.

Comment: I agree, infact even Apple's documentation on the subject strongly discourages multi-window apps.  They state an App should have 1 window, and multi-VIEW (if the app so desires).

Comment: The only time to have more than one window is if you've got a second display device, e.g. I created an app with a separate 3d view for display on a tv that is displaying content other than what is shown on the iPad.

Comment: I can think of a very good reason for another UIWindow and that is during development.  I am working on an engine that owns a UIWindow for the game, and a UIWindow (only in DEBUG builds) for the development environment (think text editor for scripting), so that I can work on my game on the iPad when out and about.  Is it possible to have more than one UIWindow?  Obviously the final game uses just one UIWindow as the development environment is not included.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad idea to rotate a custom alert to an orientation that is not supported by an application. Anyway. To prevent a status bar rotation you should remove your second window

```
[alertWindow setHidden:YES]; 
[alertWindow release]; 
alertWindow=nil;
```

after disappearence of your alert.

You also might consider usefull this liks:

- https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog
- [https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog)
- https://github.com/kyoshikawa/ZPopoverController
- https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView